# On iOS, is there a way to detect a web page runs in the embedded browser and open the "real" one?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, web-frontend

My web site uses magic links for login, however, I have a problem on mobile (not sure about Android - haven't tried yet, but the problem exists at least on iOS): when a user receives the email say in the GMail app, the link opens in the embedded browser, meaning that cookies will not be passed to the "real" browser.

Is there a way to ensure the link in the email opens in the real system browser and therefore cookies are stored permanently?

(Essentially browser session isolation on iOS breaks a lot of things on the Internet, so surely there is a workaround?)

Comment: What happens with native mail app ?

Comment: @PtitXav Mail opens links properly in the main browser app. I think thre reason GMail does this in the embedded browser is, they want to have control of at least the URL's you visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research: no, it is not possible to detect you are in an embedded browser, neither is it possible to enforce opening a link in the system one. Makes sense from security point of view.

However, **I was asking the wrong question**. The problem of a magic link login is solved differently: when starting a login process you can set a session cookie and create an associated DB record for it, marking it as blocked, i.e. not logged in.

At next step, when the magic link is opened in whatever browser you unblock the session in the DB. At this stage you can replace the login cookie with a real one, e.g. JWT, or continue using it as your main auth token.

If the user then returns to the real browser, you check the login cookie and act accordingly, keeping in mind that it may not be the browser where they validated the magic link. At this stage you can, again, replace the login cookie with your real auth cookie knowing that the session has been validated already.

I'm not entirely sure this is 100% safe, need to think about it more but at first glance it does look safe and seems to be pretty much the only way of handling magic links on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The danger here (specially with the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70767216/2054848) above) is that it allows a malicious actor to request a magic login link from any browser / device, and then if the user clicks on the link (either unknowingly or perhaps near a time where they have requested one themselves), the malicious actor will then be logged in.

One way to protect against this is to provide a random code in the email which the user has to input into the original browser to confirm it is truly them (though UX isn’t as great). This is similar to OTPs and SMS logins, and should have time restrictions on the use of the code.

Another (less safe) option is:

1. the user opens clicks the link in their email and it opens their browser/in-app browser
2. check if the browser is the same one used to request (e.g. via a cookie)
3. if it is a different browser, ask the user to confirm if they want the original browser to be logged-in (perhaps showing the original browser’s location and device)
   Though, like the selected answer, this relies on users not unknowingly or lazily clicking to allow it, so is fallible to careless user interactions.